# Determining the scrollbar movement in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

In my application, I use two scrollbars and handle the movement of the slider in them using the function:

```
afx_msg void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
```

But this function should be responsible for responding to the movement of both sliders. How can I find out which of these two sliders has been moved?

Comment: You can call `pScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID()`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/slider-notification-messages?view=msvc-170